# How to make in Android EditText with Button like in iOS?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

Can I do something similar with image below in Android default way?
See example image [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8PY9GkvB5pTVnQxaEpaWFM4U2s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you make your editbox with correct graphic and then you put another button beside it.

Comment: but how to do it like [this](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8PY9GkvB5pTVnQxaEpaWFM4U2s)

Comment: You remove the padding from either button or editbox. There is padding on the default graphic to editbox so you need to create your own background for the editbox. You find it under (for api lvl 8): Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi and then editbox_background_normal.9